# Generating dynamic YAML file from a for loop in Python

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a `template.yml` with below contents:

```
hostname:
   image: my_image:latest
   script:
    - ansible -m command -a "echo Hi"  hostname
```

Using python, I need to read a `.txt`file with below contents:

```
server1.example.com
server2.example.com
server3.example.com
...
```

and using some loop and replace the hostname variable in both places in above `template.yml`. The all configs need to be in a single `output.yml` file.

I have been trying to use python yaml library and its yaml.update and yaml.dump features but had no luck in storing all the generated configs in the same output file. Any help with this is appreciated.

Updates:

I have added the code I tried below:

```
import yaml

def generate_yml(host):
    with open('template.yml') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f)
        config['hostname']['script'] = "ansible -m command -a 'echo Hi' " + host
    return config

    with open('output.yml', 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(config, f, default_flow_style=False)

hostfile = open("test.txt", "r")
for host in hostfile:
    host = host.rstrip("\n")
    generate_yml(host)
myfile.close()
```

and for `yaml_update`, I tried:

```
    with open('output.yml','r') as f:
        config = yaml.load(yamlfile)
        config['hostname']['script'] = "ansible -m command -a 'echo Hi' " + host  
        config['hostname'].update(config)
        
    with open('output.yml', 'w') as yamlfile:
        yaml.dump(config, yamlfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

Both approaches write the configs for only last entry in the `.txt`file and also first hostname variable in `template.yml` is not taken into account.

Comment: it would be helpful to provide the sample input file and sample output file(s) and the code that you tried that didn't work

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia Added the details.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia I am looking for something like this: https://pastebin.com/e6JLwVMN

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in the current code:

1. With `return config`, you are just exiting the function without writing to the file.
2. You open the file in write mode `w` every time so the contents get overwritten.
3. You are adding the `script` part as a string object but it should be a `list` for the right `yaml`.

The correct implementation should be:

```
import yaml
def generate_yml(host):
    with open('template.yml') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f)
        config[host] = config['hostname'].copy()
        config[host]['script'] = ["ansible -m command -a 'echo Hi' " + host] # add the command as a list for the correct yaml
        del config['hostname']   # del the 'hostname' key from config

    with open('output.yml', 'a') as f: # open the file in append mode
        yaml.dump(config, f, default_flow_style=False)

hostfile = open("test.txt", "r")
for host in hostfile:
    host = host.rstrip("\n")
    generate_yml(host)

hostfile.close()
```

Output:

```
server1.example.com:
  image: my_image:latest
  script:
  - ansible -m command -a 'echo Hi' server1.example.com
server2.example.com:
  image: my_image:latest
  script:
  - ansible -m command -a 'echo Hi' server2.example.com
server3.example.com:
  image: my_image:latest
  script:
  - ansible -m command -a 'echo Hi' server3.example.com
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the job.

Answer (score 1):

YAML is not a templating engine. Have you considered using a templating engine?

This is how you could do it with pystache:

```py
import pystache, yaml

input = """
{{#hostnames}}
{{.}}:
   image: my_image:latest
   script:
    - ansible -m command -a "echo Hi"  {{.}}
{{/hostnames}}
"""

vars = """
server1.example.com
server2.example.com
server3.example.com
"""

print(pystache.render(input, {"hostnames": [h for h in vars.splitlines() if h]}))
```

Output:

```yaml
server1.example.com:
   image: my_image:latest
   script:
    - ansible -m command -a "echo Hi"  server1.example.com
server2.example.com:
   image: my_image:latest
   script:
    - ansible -m command -a "echo Hi"  server2.example.com
server3.example.com:
   image: my_image:latest
   script:
    - ansible -m command -a "echo Hi"  server3.example.com
```

Compared to actually parsing the input as YAML, you can keep formatting (e.g. comments and original indentation) when using a templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
It loads the template as a dictionary, and forms a new dictionary with proper `hostname` substitution for each host, and dumps the whole thing to the `output.yml` file. Note that this requires PyYaml - `pip insatll pyyaml`

```
import yaml


with open("./template.yml") as f:
    template = yaml.load(f)

HOSTS = [
    "host_a",
    "host_b",
    "host_c"
]

output = {host: template["hostname"] for host in HOSTS}


with open("./output.yml", "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(output, f)
```

Comment: This fails with `output = {host: template["hostname"]) for host in HOSTS}
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @slal, sorry, I added an extra `)`. I edited the answer, please try again